# `# ssh myuser@myhost` = Permission Denied but `su myuser` THEN `$ ssh myhost` works.. why?

Tags: ssh, centos7

Consider the following commands. How can this happen?

```
[root@mylocal ~]# ssh myuser@myhost
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
[root@mylocal ~]# su myuser
[myuser@mylocal ~]$ ssh myhost
Welcome Last login: Sat Oct 20 16:28:48 2018 from mylocal 
[myuser@myhost~]$
```

please advise how to cure it so that I can do as root,

```
[root@mylocal ~]# ssh myuser@myhost   
Welcome Last login: Sat Oct 20 16:28:48 2018 from mylocal 
[myuser@myhost~]$
```

thanks

Comment: Hi, please use the contact us at the bottom, they can remove it or atleast dissasociate it from your acoount, Thanks

Comment: @yagmoth555 they have to remove it under GDPR it's the law, I am the author, I am not putting up with a honest question getting minus 6 for no reason - and neither should you shame on you guys for letting this place deteriorate so massively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default identities used are in the localuser's home directory, not any remote user.

For OpenSSH, the configuration file mentioned in the manual is a hint to configure a different identity matching those criteria. See the ssh_config man page.

Edit ~root/.ssh/config  and add

```
Match User myuser
  IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
  IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
  IdentityFile /home/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
```

SSH identities absolutely should not be public readable. This only works because root can read anything.  Non privileged users can put a copy in their own home directory with some other name,  say `~/.ssh/myuser`

Comment: @MrHeelis - you can do that by selecting the open tick next to this answer. That'll move the acceptance from the other answer to this one.

Answer (score 3):

> -i identity_file 
>   Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for RSA or DSA authentication is read. The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_dsa for protocol version 2. Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the configuration file. It is possible to have multiple -i options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).

Comment: correct `# ssh myuser@myhost -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa` works. How i it best to mitigate this? So that myuser@myhost ssh connections know to use /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa by default or that I alter the file contents - and is that on the client or the server?

Comment: i've accepted you answer but it remains sub-optimal: my question remains - "how to cure it so that.. "